# Rails string split every other "."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bunch of sentences that I want to break into an array. Right now, I'm splitting every time \n appears in the string.

```
@chapters = @script.split('\n')
```

What I'd like to do is .split ever OTHER "." in the string. Is that possible in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a regex, but I'd start with a simple approach: just split on periods, then join pairs of substrings:

```rb
s = "foo. bar foo. foo bar. boo far baz. bizzle"
s.split(".").each_slice(2).map {|p| p.join "." }
# => => ["foo. bar foo", " foo bar. boo far baz", " bizzle"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where it's easier to use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan) than [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split).

We can use the following regular expression:

```
r = /(?<=\.|\A)[^.]*\.[^.]*(?=\.|\z)/
```

```
str=<<~_
Now is the time. This is it. It is now. The time to have fun.
The time to make new friends. The time to party.
_
```

```
str.scan(r)
  #=> [
  #    "Now is the time. This is it",
  #    " It is now. The time to have fun",
  #    "\nThe time to make new friends. The time to party"
  #=> ]
```

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    (?<=     # begin a positive lookbehind
      \A     # match the beginning of the string
      |      # or
      \.     # match a period
    )        # end positive lookbehind
    [^.]*    # match zero or more characters other than periods
    \.       # match a period
    [^.]*    # match zero or more characters other than periods
    (?=      # begin a positive lookahead
      \.     # match a period
      |      # or
      \z     # match the end of the string
    )        # end positive lookahead
    /x       # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Note that `(?<=\.|\A)` can be replaced with `(?<![^\.])`. `(?<![^\.])` is a *negative lookbehind* that asserts the match is not preceded by a character other than a period.

Similarly, `(?=\.|\z)` can  be replaced with `(?![^.])`. `(?![^.])` is a *negative lookahead* that asserts the match is not followed by a character other than a period.